# New Android Eclipse version won't get to workspace

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to start out with Android programming (I'm running Mac OS X Lion). I had an old version of Eclipse and installed ADT version 20 in it, and code didn't compile properly. Fine; I hadn't done much in there, and after reading some stuff here it sounded like the easiest thing for the long run would be to put together a completely new installation.

So I downloaded the latest version of Android, with the SDK, from the Android developer Getting Started site, and ran it (in its own directory). I loaded one of my previous workspaces and it said that one wouldn't work because the ADT was version 20 and it needs 21. I figured fine, there wasn't much in there and I'd just start a new workspace.

So I started a new workspace, and here's where the real trouble came: It gives me the start screen with newbie welcome instructions but won't go any further than that. When I try to create a new Android Application Project, it goes through the menus but as soon as I click Finish I get a please-wait circular icon, and little happens. There's a line at the bottom that says "66M of 142M" - it increases slowly into the 80s and then drops back down into the 60s, endlessly. And the links provided on the welcome page (Building Your First App, etc.) don't work - I click on them and nothing happens.

Any idea what's going wrong here? Is there some cruft left over in my system from older versions, which I should delete? If so, how should I go about doing that? If not, what else might I try to get it working?

Comment: ... Okay, so eventually it created the project and it worked. It just took a VERY long time - several minutes. Then when I tried to create a new project, the same thing - a good five minutes to load. My computer is a MacBook Pro with 2.4 GHz processor and 4 MB memory; it shouldn't be running this slowly. The previous version of Eclipse wasn't nearly this slow. Any idea why it's taking so painfully long?

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment beneath yours because of my level, but you can **help Eclipse run faster by [giving it more memory](https://superuser.com/questions/298451/allocating-more-memory-to-eclipse)**. Doing this speeds things up quite a bit.

As far as installations go, **maybe try Google's packaged version of Eclipse + Android SDK**. The whole package is available [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). It's already preconfigured to work and provides eclipse with ADT installed by default. Of course, if you already have an existing Eclipse you want to modify this won't help you too much. But if you're new to Eclipse it's a good way to get started with Android development.